# If $B \subseteq C$, then $(A-C) \subseteq (A-B)$ (by element method)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I am supposed to prove that if $B\subseteq C$, then $(A-C) \subseteq (A-B)$ by the element method, but I am not really sure where to start.

I believe that you could let $x \in (A-C)$ and you are supposed to show that $x \in (A-B)$, but I'm not sure how to go from Point A to Point B.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** $x\in A-C$ if and only if $x\in A$ and $x\not\in C$. You want to show that $x\in A-B$, i.e. $x\in A$ and $x\not\in B$. $x\in A$ should be obvious, so it remains to show that $x\not\in B$. Why is that?

Comment: $x \notin B$ because B is a subset of C and we know that $x \notin C$? Is that correct?

Comment: @giggybyte, yes, that's a proof by contradiction. It is customary to upvote answers that you find helpful and accept the answer that you think is the most helpful to you. You don't need to accept my answer if you think somebody else might give you a better one, and in general, you should always wait with accepting a bit in case that a later answer is better.

Comment: There seems to be a rule that upvotes from people with less than 15 upvotes are not visible, so I'm sorry if you don't see anything. Thanks again for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

$B \subset C$ :

$x \in B$ implies $x \in C$ or equivalently

$\star):$  $y \not \in C$ implies $y \not \in B.$

Show $A-C \subset A-B:$

$y \in A-C$ implies

$y \not \in C$ and $y \in A;$

By $\star)$: $y \not \in C$ implies  $y \not \in B.$

Thus we have $y \not \in B$ and $y \in A$, or

$ y \in A-B.$